# How do i test my antispam code against bots?

Tags: security

I have some code and i wonder how it would stand up against bots. Is there a way i can either run a bot to check the strength of my site or to set real live spam bots on it in a prerelease test? (i can use something.noip.com as a dummy domain)

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Use an existing (and proven) API, such as Akismet

Comment: i am using Akismet. But i would like to give it extra punch. Most of it is invisible javascript code and honeypots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can improve the google ranking of your site to attract more bots and you can as Edouard wrote, install some bots and try to "break" your tests. Although I don't think that the "good" bots are downloadable for free.

I'd go for a higher google rank and placing your url in many places on the web to raise the chance that it gets picked up.
Place it in your footer in forums, etc. Use it in your footer in high traffic mailinglists.

But don't post there just to place your url, this will make people angry if they notice it (and justifiably so)

Answer (score 2):

You could always just drop by some of the shadier channels on IRC, and brag about your super-secret new breakthrough in software that is able to stop 100% of all spam bots which will get you the hot babes.  Be as irritating as possible, and keep poking around the area....  Eventually, you'll provoke SOMEBODY :)

Comment: hahahahhahahhahah +1 for the humor. I wouldnt know how to find the shadier irc channels but i'll keep it in mind in case i get ideas >: -)

Answer (score 1):

You answered your own question. Set up bots and run them against your site to see if it works well.

Over the time, as the popularity of your site rises, bots will spam you. You will need to keep the race going on as bots get better and better.

Comment: Writing my own bots would be useless. I would know how to counter them and it isnt the same as real bots which use javascript and whatever else they may use.

Comment: I never said you should write your own bots, I said you should set up bots, implying you should get one of the many you may find on the internet.

Answer (score 0):

Just publish it and make the page available to search engine spiders and other traffic.  They will eventually find you!